# Unable to install pglogical on Mac OS

Tags: postgresql, pglogical

I'm having real trouble installing the extension pglogical on Mac.

Cloned the [pglogical repo](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical)

When executing `make install` I get the following error:

```
macuser$ make install
sed 's/__PGLOGICAL_VERSION__/2.4.1/;s/__REQUIRES__//' 
 /Users/macuser/temp/pglogical/pglogical.control.in > 
 /Users/macuser/temp/pglogical/pglogical.control
 clang -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement - 
Werror=vla -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict- 
aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -Wno-compound-token-split-by-macro 
-O2   -I/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/include - 
I/Users/macuser/temp/pglogical/compat12 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration 
-I. -I./ -I/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/include/server - 
I/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/include/internal -I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/70.1/include 
-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk
I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include   -c -o 
pglogical_apply.o pglogical_apply.c
 pglogical_apply.c:13:10: fatal error: 'postgres.h' file not found
 #include "postgres.h"
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [pglogical_apply.o] Error 1
```

My concern is the directories that are shown in the error stack:

```
-I/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/include/server
```

For my install the postgres.h file is actually located here:

```
/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/include/postgresql/server
```

Same goes for the `include` directory. Its missing the postgresql folder in this path.

I can hard code the location of the postgres.h file in the pglogical_apply.c, but that pushes me to the next 'missing directory' include error.

I ran this version of make install as detailed in the Postgres wiki with the same error.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Building_and_Installing_PostgreSQL_Extension_Modules

I'm on Monteray 12.2.1 and have a single Pg12 installed.

How can I get make to reference the correct directory. ?

edit:

```
macuser$ make 
PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.10_1/bin/pg_config 
install
.......
pglogical_apply.c:13:10: fatal error: 'postgres.h' file not found
```

`select * from pg_configure ;`

```
BINDIR            | /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.10_1/bin
DOCDIR            | /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.10_1/share/doc/postgresql@12
HTMLDIR           | /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.10_1/share/doc/postgresql@12
INCLUDEDIR        | /usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/include
PKGINCLUDEDIR     | /usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/include
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER | /usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/include/server
LIBDIR            | /usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/lib
PKGLIBDIR         | /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.10_1/lib/postgresql
LOCALEDIR         | /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.10_1/share/locale
MANDIR            | /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.10_1/share/man
SHAREDIR          | /usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/share/postgresql@12
SYSCONFDIR        | /usr/local/etc/postgresql
PGXS              | /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.10_1/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
```

Comment: It seems very odd that it didn't fail at the plain `make` stage. What does `pg_config` think your directories should be?

Comment: Follow the directions in the Wiki link and point `make` at the location for `pg_config`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I did that, thats why I'm here. For whatever reason. It fails to produce/use the correct paths.

Comment: You show running `make install` the Wiki shows `make PG_CONFIG=path_to_postgresql_installation/bin/pg_config install`. I am not seeing how they are the same thing?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver same issue, truncated output included

Comment: @RichardHuxton Looks like the config has mis-matching paths. Could this be it ?

Comment: How did you install Postgres on this machine?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver with homebrew

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if `Homebrew` is even installing the headers? Do you see `postgres.h` under `/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/include/server`?

Comment: this location doesn't exist on my machine. For me to get to 'server' I have to navigate to `/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/include/postgres/server`

Comment: 1) That is weird as `pg_config` says `/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/include/server` is the location. 2) Was `postgres.h` there? 3) Did you get the Homebrew from here [Postgresql](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/postgresql) or here [homebrew-postgresql](https://github.com/petere/homebrew-postgresql)?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the former [Postgresql](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/postgresql)

Comment: So was `postgres.h` there?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver no it was no.

Comment: Then this something you will need to bring up the Homebrew maintainer.